# Java Output Variable Scope Issue

Tags: java, variables, scope

I have an issue regarding variable scope in the following piece of code. Can someone give a quick overview as to why java "cannot find the symbol" for output when it is printed? Thanks.

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "hello";
        if (text.indexOf(" ") == -1) //if a space doesn't exist
        {
            String output = "one word";
        }
        else
        {
            String output = "more than one word";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: you may read this article: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `output` is *only* existent within the containing code block which currently seems to be within the `if` block and `else` block, if you want to access the variable `output` outside of the `if` and `else` block, you'll need to define it before the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

**Local variables**

A local variable is the one that is declared within a method or a constructor (not in the header). The scope and lifetime are limited to the method itself.

In addition to the local variables defined in a method, we also have variables that are defined in blocks, e.g. the if block and an the else block. The scope in this case is constrained by the block itself.